# “ls -l” shows some abnormal files with “?”

Tags: filesystems

Recently I ran into a problem with FTP server access. The server system logs shows that `/etc/wu-ftpd/ftpaccess` file is missing, as below:

> wu-ftpd[15695]: cannot open access file /etc/wu-ftpd/ftpaccess: No
>   such file or directory

After listing the contents of `/etc/`, I found serverl files were abnormal and the output contains several `"?"`, and there is no `/etc/wu-ftpd/` at all:

```
?--------- ? ? ? ? ? inputrc

?--------- ? ? ? ? ? nsswitch.conf.nis

?--------- ? ? ? ? ? pam.conf

?--------- ? ? ? ? ? syslog/ng

?--------- ? ? ? ? ? wu/ftpd
```

Is there any possible reason to cause such abnormal things, like disk problem, file system crash, or inadvertent human operation?

Comment: What is output of `ls -ld /etc`?

Comment: Here is it:
ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 76 root root 4096 May 12 18:36 /etc

Comment: Did you copy+paste that output, or type it manually? Can you double check it's exactly correct?

Comment: I used copy and paste. Anything related to the directory permission?

Comment: What command did you use to get the output shown in your question?  Was it `ls -l /etc` (or something very similar)?  If so, that is *very* strange; such a command should never list filenames that contain slashes (e.g., `syslog/ng` and `wu/ftpd`).  Is `/etc` the only directory that has a problem?  Are all the files in `/etc` bad, or just a few?  You could have a severely corrupted filesystem.

Comment: Actually here was the command in use:

root@XXXSPA:/etc# ls -l
total 1248
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root     4096 May 31  2008 X11
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     2188 Mar 27  2008 adduser.conf
...
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     1049 Mar 27  2008 watchdog.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     4022 Mar 27  2008 wggtrc
?---------  ? ?    ?           ?            ? wu/ftpd

Not all the files under /etc/ were bad. Just a few files or directories are listed with "?". Could it be related to bad disk drive, or just file system problem?

Comment: Sorry for the mess of linefeed. I used notepad for editing and copied from it...

Answer (score 2):

I have another answer - filesystem not corrupt, the execute permission on directory is not set.

Try this:  (any linux but tested on CentOS 7.3)

```
cdir=MasterTest/config
mkdir -p $cdir/flue
touch $cdir/flue/goo
chmod 440 $cdir/*
chmod 440 $cdir/$DESC_FILE
ls -alstr $cdir

ls: cannot access MasterTest/config/flue: Permission denied
ls: cannot access MasterTest/config/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access MasterTest/config/.: Permission denied
total 0
? d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? flue
? d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
? d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
```

To recover:

```
chmod +x $cdir/
ls -alstr $cdir
total 12
4 drwxr-xr-x 3 me me 4096 May 19 14:25 ..
4 dr-xr-x--x 3 me me 4096 May 19 14:25 .
4 dr--r----- 2 me me 4096 May 19 14:25 flue
```

Comment: This is the total Correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

That is the result of filesystem corruption. The directory (which is just a file, too) lists entries that don't point to valid inodes.  You should run `fsck` for whatever filesystem that is. Generally speaking, the filesystem must not be mounted when checked.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually the system rebooted several times, but the issue was still there. I was expecting fsck to be run automatically in such scenario, isn't it true?

Comment: Depends on the filesystem. xfs, for example, doesn't have an `fsck` (xfs_check and xfs_repair) Journaled fs's just replay the log and assume everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks. Our server is running ext3. Is it normal that fsck does not run after system reboot to fix the problem?

Comment: By default, ext3 is checked by fsck automatically after *n* days or *m* mounts without check.  AFAIK fsck doesn't automatically detect a corrupted filesystem at boot, let alone run and fix it.